# Send multiples commands with ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, java-8, child-process, processbuilder

I want to spawn a child process in Java and send different commands inside the app. My child process has authentication and each user can have a variety of internal commands.

For example:

```
> login myuser passowrd
OK
> list certs
cert1 abc
cert2 efg
> logout
> exit
```

Well, to simulate that I will make my example with "node" as IO CLI.

```java
public class JAVAMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        action();
    }

    public static String action() throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();

        // streams
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        String buff = "";
        String res = "";

        System.out.println("1");
        writer.write("console.log('OK');\n"); // simulate "login answer"
        writer.flush();

        System.out.println("2");
        res = "";
        while ((buff = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            res += buff;
        }

        if (!res.equals("OK")) {
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            throw new Exception("Invalid auth");
        }

        System.out.println("3");
        writer.write("console.log('any text...');\n");
        writer.flush();

        System.out.println("4");
        res = "";
        while ((buff = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            res += buff;
        }

        reader.close();
        writer.close();
        return res;
    }
}
```

I expect to print `1,2,3,4` and get the res `any text...` for this example. But the program never stops and stay in `1,2`. If I close the `writer` after the flush in `1` I get this output:

```
1
2
3
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:221)
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
        at com.keynua.kades.JAVAMain2.action(JAVAMain2.java:48)
        at com.keynua.kades.JAVAMain2.main(JAVAMain2.java:14)
```

That's why I close the `writer` and the `reader` works but I can't write again. So, how I can make to send multiples commands to the child app and read the output to follow the flow with other commands?

Comment: I think you could probably achieve what you want using a GUI rather than trying to simulate a terminal window of the operating system, for example a command prompt window in Windows. I feel you are asking how to make your implementation (of simulating a terminal window) work. Perhaps if you described what you are trying to achieve, you may get an answer describing how to achieve it.

Comment: @Abra I can say it is like a terminal but in background. I want to send commands to a program and get the output to send another command.

Comment: Personally, I use `ProcessBuilder` to execute a single command. If I need to execute a second command based on the output of the first command, I save the output of the first command in my java code and I create a separate `ProcessBuilder` to execute the second command. I'm not saying that's how you should do it, I'm just explaining how I do it. Yes, I know it doesn't answer your question. (That's why this is just a comment :-)

Comment: @Abra If I don't find a solution, I will have to do that. I don't like it at all because I'm going to have to login for each "bulk" of command

Comment: Join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216731/room-for-abra-and-jtwalters) ?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that your while loops

```
while ((buff = reader.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

only terminate when the `reader` has reached the end of the input stream.

The end of the input stream is only reached when the subprocess terminates.

---

The second problem is that you seem to be using NodeJS as sample command executor.

- If NodeJS is started from a console, you can enter JavaScript statements and they are executed one by one.
- You are however starting NodeJS not from a console, but from some other application. In this case, NodeJS wants to read a complete script from stdin and executes the complete script at once
- You could start NodeJS with the `-i` parameter (force interactive mode), at the expense of some additional output.

To achieve this, you would create the `ProcessBuilder` with

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node", "-i");
```

---

Communicating with a subprocess in this way only works when you know how many lines to read from the `reader` before sending the next command.

Knowing how many lines to read can mean:

- knowing how many lines of output a command produces (login: 1 line of output, logout: no output)
- knowing that a command produces a distinct last line (for example an empty line or a line with only "END" in it)
- that a command produces a line count as the first result
- executing another command first that returns the result line count of the subsequent command

---

The `list certs` command could either:

- produce

  ```
    cert1 abc
    cert2 def
    END
  ```
- produce (where the last line would be empty instead of containing a dot)

  ```
    cert1 abc
    cert2 def
    .
  ```
- produce

  ```
    2 certs
    cert1 abc
    cert2 def
  ```
- or you could execute a `count certs` command before executing `list certs`

Comment: If I remove the loop and put `res = reader.readLine();` for the login still waiting in that part. Even if I make `"console.log('OK');\n"` twice. Only works if I close the `writer`, but I need to run the next commands only if is a valid user

Comment: Are you sure the subprocess is waiting for `\n` and not `\r\n`?

Comment: Did you check whether the subprocess wrote to the error stream?

Comment: @Holger, `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` merge de error stream and out stream so I no need to read the error stream. If I reed it they return me `null`

Comment: Then, there’s not much left to suggest, without knowing anything about the subprocess. Did you check whether the program works with a pipe in general?

Comment: @jtwalters I've updated my answer with information that I've gathered while experimenting with NodeJS